# Is there a way to implement a RangeSet with a ContinuousSet?

Tags: set, pyomo

I'm new with pyomo, and I have a battery model already written in pyomo, but i have a problem with the "terminal voltage" equation:
**Vt(t) = Voc(SOC) + V1(t) + V2(t) + Vs(t).**
Where Voc is the open circuit voltage, which depends on the currently State Of Charge(SOC), and the rest of terms are drops voltage across the battery.
I actually have try the program with a constant value of 'Voc' and it works, but i need that this value keep changing over the time (while SOC grows up). I have the logaritm regresion equation obtained in excel:
**y = 0.1164ln(x) + 2.816.** Where 'x' would be 'SOC'.
I've tried combining two sets: ContinuousSet which is the time, and RangeSet, which is the SOC, but doesn't works, here is a part of the code:

```
m.t = ContinuousSet(bounds = (0,300)) #Dominio del tiempo continuo
m.s = RangeSet(0, 100) #Valores SOC 0-100%
```

The equation that gives me a trouble:

```
m.ode_OpenC = Constraint(m.s, rule = lambda m, s: m.OpenC[s] == 0.1164*math.log(m.SOC[t]*100) + 2.816)
```

And the error message:
*ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint ode_OpenC with*
*index 0: NameError: name 't' is not defined*
*ERROR: Constructing component 'ode_OpenC' from data=None failed: NameError:*
*name 't' is not defined*

I've tried also to add the 't' and the 'SOC' value to and nparray but it presents an error too.

Do you know how to solve it?
Thank you for your attention

Comment: I don't think your problem is with sets...  Can you edit your post and add a little more detail covering `OpenC` and `Voc`.  So as I read this, Voc is a function of Soc and Soc is a function of time.  Are these variables in your model or are they parameters (known values that can be computed)?

Comment: I read your first phrase and realized that i didn't need that RangeSet, I used Voc in the time function and it works, I was some confused...
And yes, both are variables, thanku so much